# Immutable class while using a cache

Tags: java, multithreading, immutability

While going through `JCIP`, I came across the below code snippet which was considered as `Immutable`. However the explanation provided makes me confused.

> OneValueCache wouldn't be immutable without the copyOf calls in the constructor and getter. Arrays.copyOf was added as a convenience in
> Java 6; clone would also work.

Aren't the `state vars` of `OneValueCache` themselves `Immutable` with `final` and `BigInteger` being itself `immutable`? Why do we need to have `Arrays.copyOf` if the state of `OneValueCache` is already `Immutable`?

```
class OneValueCache {

private final BigInteger lastNumber;
private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;

public OneValueCache(BigInteger i,
BigInteger[] factors) {
lastNumber = i;
lastFactors = Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);
}

public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i) {
  if (lastNumber == null || !lastNumber.equals(i))
    return null;
  else
    return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
}
}
```

Comment: Define your terms. By `JCIP` did you mean the book [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://jcip.net/)?

Comment: Your code sample needs its formatting/indenting fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `final` applies to `lastFactors`, but not to the elements of `lastFactors`. If the methods returned `lastFactors` directly without copying it, the caller could modify the elements of `lastFactors` without any problems, changing the internal state of `OneValueCache`. With the copy operations, the returned arrays are copies of the final variable, and any modifications will modify the copy of the array, not the immutable instance.